# Why is my Flag Declined?

Tags: discussion, moderators, flagging, specific-flag

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370139/the-equation-and-number-of-units

Question was flagged by me and declined. But now this question is closed.What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Note that it was closed for a different reason ("not constructive") than the one stated in your flag ("too localized")... Other than that I don't know.

Comment: Both are like "question will not help future visitors, OP has not given any approach".

Answer (score 6):

Almost all homework problems are "too localized" in the sense that the solution to **that specific problem** will not help anybody else, but of course the concepts or techniques behind the solution to such a problem *can* be helpful to others, and so such problems are (and always have been) perfectly welcome here.

Your comment above mentions that you also intended your flag to indicate that the OP did not present any work. Unless this user is a recurring problem and refuses to show any work after having been asked to several times on multiple questions, *this is definitely not a valid reason to flag either*. If the user is still new, I'd recommend just leaving a comment explaining how they can improve their question, and why. When you're flagging something, your first question should not be "Does this flag reason sound like it applies?", it should be "Is this something the community can handle on its own, or does it require special moderator attention?" As a moderator, I can tell you I don't want to see the flag queue filled with hundreds of "too localized" or "not constructive" flags on questions where someone didn't ask their question in an ideal way, leaving the occasional flag concerning a spammer or sockpuppeteer buried in the mix. If someone is posting lots of poor questions without responding to any requests for their own thoughts, feel free to flag then, but be sure to explain that that is what is happening in the flag - don't rely on one of the predefined reasons to explain what you mean.

In summary: though I of course appreciate your interest in helping out, I would ask that you reserve your moderator flags for the times they are needed - the community does a good job of self-moderation already, and can close and even delete poor material when necessary.

P.S. The fact that a question was closed for a particular stated reason does not necessarily imply that that is the actual reason (after all, there is a fixed list of reasons to choose from), and moreover does not imply that it actually should have been closed.

Comment: But close flags can also be handled by 10k users, not only by diamond moderators.

Comment: @MadScientist: I had been under the impression that 10k users could only deem them valid or invalid, not clear them from the queue - did this change?

Comment: They can't declare them invalid, but the flags get dismissed when the question is closed (and also if another close vote is cast and the question is put into the close review queue, if I'm not mistaken). But all that will change in the flag overhaul in the near future anyway.

Comment: Zev, in the case of closure flags, 10k users can actually vote to close the question; or invalidate the flag.

Comment: See also the discussion in the comments to this meta post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/flaggin-contradiction